# Calling SOAP webservice through AWS Lambda in python using zeep library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, soap, aws-lambda, zeep

I am trying to make SOAP call using zeep library from AWS ALambda in python.The request requires HTTP Basic Authentication and wsdl is at https protocol so I setter `session.verify=false` as well. Below is my Lambda code.Is this the correct way of making SOAP call from python.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = 'wsdl-url'
    session = Session()
    session.verify = False
    session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('userid', 'password')
    transport = Transport(session=session)
    client = Client(wsdl=url, transport=transport)
    client.transport.session.verify = False
body="""
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver= http:www.xyz.org/Version_4.1_Release" xmlns:cpsm="cpsm">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ver:XYZMsgHeader MajorVersion="?" MinorVersion="?" Build="?" Branch="?" BuildString="?" UserID="" Pwd="" AppName="?" AppVersion="?" Company="?" DefaultCurrencyCode="?" CSUnits="feet" CoordinateSystemName="?" CoordinateSystemAuthority="?" CoordinateSystemAuthorityCode="?" Datum="?" SessionID="?" PreviousSessionID="?" ObjectsRemaining="?" LastSent="?" RegistrationID="?" MessageID="?" TimeStamp="?" Context="?"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:Notification xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="cpsm" xmlns:ns1="http www.xyz.org/Version_4.1_Release">
         <ns1:events>
            <ns1:ABCLog verb="Change">
               <ns1:ABCID>C101</ns1:ABCID>
               <ns1:ABCStateList>
                  <ns1:ABCState verb="Change">
                     <ns1:GMTTime>2019-1020T18:57:33Z</ns1:GMTTime>
                     <ns1:GPS>
                        <ns1:latitude>45.316550303492</ns1:latitude>
                        <ns1:longitude>-122.774259911433</ns1:longitude>
                     </ns1:GPS>
                     <ns1:telemetry>
                        <ns1:speed units="mph">000.000</ns1:speed>
                     </ns1:telemetry>
                  </ns1:ABCState>
               </ns1:ABCStateList>
            </ns1:ABCLog>
         </ns1:events>
      </ns1:Notification>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

    response = client.service.Notification(body)
    print('response: ', response)
```

But when I run this program in local pycharm ide, getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/MyLambda/etl-lambda.py", line 289, in <module>
    lambda_handler(None, None)
  File "C:/Users/Documents/MyLambda/etl-lambda.py", line 82, in lambda_handler
    response = client.service.Notification(body)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 229, in render
    element_value = value[name]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please guide.

Comment: Can you please tell us the wsdl url ?

Comment: or post the output of `python -mzeep wsdl-url` replace the `wsdl-url` with original url. thanks

Comment: If it's ok for your, I'd like to know how you imported the zeep in your lambda function. Did you create a layer for zeep and if so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using below code:

```
request_data = \
        {
            'Notification':{
                'events':{
                    'ABCLog':{
                        'ABCID': 'C101',
                        'ABCStateList': {
                            'ABCState':{
                                'GMTTime': '2019-1020T18:57:33Z',
                                'GPS':{
                                    'latitude':'45.316550303492',
                                    'longitude':'-122.774259911433'
                                },
                                'telemetry':{
                                    'speed':'000.000'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
```

and the called zeep client like below:

```
response = client.service.Notification(events=[request_data ])
```

Zeep library takes care of xml formatting.